# static x265 not found while compiling FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation

Can configure ffmpeg with x265 shared library but with the static library it does not work:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --disable-static --pkg-config-flags="--static" --extra-cflags=-I./include --extra-ldflags=-L./lib --extra-libs=-ldl --extra-cflags=-DPTW32_STATIC_LIB
```

> ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config

Also changed x265.pc before making static x265

Libs: -L${libdir} -lx265 -lstdc++ -lm -lrt

/usr/local/lib is having libx265.a static file

Comment: What does `ffbuild/config.log` say?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/libx265.a(encoder.cpp.o): In function `x265::Encoder::destroy()':
encoder.cpp:(.text+0x7e1): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'

Comment: I see mulitple issues /tmp/ffconf.GT1cCjGX/test.c:1:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 
#include <windows.h>
                     

^compilation terminated.

it is able to find the static library but some undefined reference 

/usr/local/lib/libx265.a(json11.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6json119JsonValueE[_ZTVN6json119JsonValueE]+0x28): more undefined references to `__cxa_pure_virtual' follow
collect2: 
error: ld returned 1 exit status

ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config

Comment: Adding `-lstdc++` to the extra libs to resolved the "undefined refence to operator ..." errors for me, like so:  `--extra-libs="-ldl -lstdc++"`.

Comment: did you ever happen to figure this out? would you post the solution?

Answer (score 4):

You need more library "libnuma-dev".

```
sudo apt-get install libx265-dev libnuma-dev
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related, but it works! Thanks!